# How to find an expression of the variance of a Poisson-Lognormal distribution?

Tags: distributions, variance, poisson-distribution, lognormal-distribution, compound-distributions

I am using a model for the number of goods in a supermarket cart with a Poisson-lognormal distribution (a lognormal mixture of Poissons).

I would like to find an expression of the variance of this pmf (probability mass function),
$$f(x;\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{x!\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{x-1} e^{-\lambda} e^{\frac{(\log(\lambda)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }\text{d}\lambda,\quad x=0,1,2, \dotsc
$$
I know from this post *[Mean of a Poisson-Lognormal Distribution (PLN)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417914/mean-of-a-poisson-lognormal-distribution-pln)*
 that the mean is  $\text{e}^{\mu+{\sigma^2 \over 2}}$.
I know that

$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\text{e}^{2\mu+\sigma^2}$

Is it possible to use the *[Law of iterated expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/law-of-iterated-expectation/)* or similar law to find $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ and an expression for the variance for the Poisson-Lognormal distribution $f(x;\mu,\sigma)$?.

Comment: Is this exponential family?

Comment: @user0 I am not sure. I know that I can sample the pdf $f$ in 3 steps: 1) compute a normally distributed value, 2) take the exponent (this will sample the lognormal) and then 3) sample a Poisson distribution with parameter the exponent value obtained in 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [law of total variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71620/law-of-total-variance-as-pythagorean-theorem) which is analogue to the double expectation theorem. If we have
$$  \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   N \mid \Lambda=\lambda \sim \mathcal{Po}(\lambda) \\
   \Lambda \sim \mathcal{logNormal}(\mu,\sigma^2)
$$
we find using [lognormal properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)
$$
\E N=\E \left[ \E  N\mid \Lambda\right] =\E \Lambda =e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}
$$ and 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}
   \V N = \E \V N \mid \Lambda + \V \E N \mid \Lambda=e^{\mu+\sigma^2/2}+[e^{\sigma^2}-1] e^{2\mu+\sigma^2}
$$